# retrospectively switch on emails for Jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins

We have a Jenkins instance with over 250 jobs installed in it. Until recently corporate rules prevented us from configuring Jenkins to send emails for build failures etc.

We have now been given permission to configure Jenkins to connect to the corporate SMTP server and I have configured one job to send emails and all is working fine. Is there an automated way to enable emails for all jobs or do I have to go into the configuration for each job and manually enable it?

If not are there any plugins or shell scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuration Slicing plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuration+Slicing+Plugin) can help in this situation.

Install this plugin, then go to `Manage Jenkins -> Configuration Slicing -> E-mail Notification`

Put email into the left column, all job names to the right column, then press Save.

[image]

Please note that it will change each job configuration and add E-mail publisher to them.